# C# UDP socket send exception when no receiver on localhost

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an app that opens a UDP socket, currently on local host to debug with a simulation.
When the app sends and there is no receiver there is an exception thrown in the background
Exception thrown:

> 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll

If the listener is on, the exception is **not** thrown.
This does not stop my app, but I'd like to handle this exception.
Any idea on how? I tried to wrap the send portion, but it doesn't seem to help.

Socket creation:

```
    private void InitUdpClient()
    {
        try
        {
            if (null != udpClient)
                udpClient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 
          //log errors to file
        }

        try
        {
            RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            udpClient = new UdpClient(rxPortNum);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log errors to file               
        }
```

Send function:

```
 public void Send(byte[] dataToSend)
    {
        try
        {
            udpClient.Send(dataToSend, dataToSend.Length, ipAddress, txPortNum);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log errors to file
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you stablish a remote host with the `Connect` method anywhere in your code? Because if so, passing a `hostname` to the `Send` method will throw a `SocketException` as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.send?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_UdpClient_Send_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_String_System_Int32_) in the *Note*

Comment: exception is only thrown when there is no remote socket open.